# Can you export a swift executable from Docker using a Windows server 2022 machine, and the call it outside of docker on the same machine type?

Tags: swift, windows, docker

I am currently building swift using docker: https://github.com/lancejpollard/swift-choco/actions/runs/7623985629/job/20765187994. The [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/lancejpollard/swift-choco/blob/make/load/docker/Dockerfile) is simple:

```
# https://github.com/apple/swift-docker/blob/main/5.9/windows/LTSC2022/Dockerfile
FROM swift:5.9.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2022
RUN echo $((Get-Command swift).Path)
```

(I am testing where the swift executable is in that one currently).

Can I just COPY the swift executable and use it in the `chocolateyinstall.ps1` like https://github.com/mkevenaar/chocolatey-packages/blob/edfc8ffb00971c46bca1e468f1fd207f789624b3/automatic/swiftforwindows/tools/chocolateyinstall.ps1 does? Something like this?

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';

$toolsDir     = "$(Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"
$url          = 'https://github.com/myorg/myswift/releases/download/v5.9.2/my-swift-from-docker.exe'
$checksum     = 'sha...'
$checksumType = 'sha256'

$packageArgs = @{
  packageName    = $env:ChocolateyPackageName
  unzipLocation  = $toolsDir
  fileType       = 'exe'
  url            = $url
  checksum       = $checksum
  checksumType   = $checksumType
  softwareName  = 'swift'
  silentArgs    = "/S"
  validExitCodes= @(0)
}

Install-ChocolateyPackage @packageArgs
```

You don't need to know chocolatey to solve this, **my main question is**:

1. Can I export the `swift.exe` or whatever it is from docker...
2. Save it in a file in a GitHub release like https://github.com/myorg/myswift/releases/download/v5.9.2/my-swift-from-docker.exe...
3. And then download that and it will just work on a windows server 2022 machine (the same as the docker image)?

I am unsure how complex these executables on windows (or any platform) work. I am not sure if they link to other dependencies I would somehow have to copy over, or if they work on their own.